# How to create subheadings using summary_table R qwraps2?

Tags: r, dplyr, summary, qwraps2

I want to produce a table of summary stats with summary_table. This needs to have subheadings.

I have been following this example:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qwraps2/vignettes/summary-statistics.html

```
stats_summary1 <-
  list("Sex (female)" =
         list("number (%)" = ~ qwraps2::n_perc(.data$sex=="F", digits = 1)),
       "Age" =
         list("min" = ~ min(.data$age_d, digits = 1),
              "max" = ~ max(.data$age_d, digits = 1),
              "median (IQR)" = ~ qwraps2::median_iqr(.data$age_d, digits = 1)),
       "Disease" =
         list("A" = ~ qwraps2::n_perc(.data$d==1, digits = 1),
              "B" = ~ qwraps2::n_perc(.data$d==2, digits = 1),
              "C" = ~ qwraps2::n_perc(.data$d==3, digits = 1),
              "D" = ~ qwraps2::n_perc(.data$d==4, digits = 1),
              "E" = ~ qwraps2::n_perc(.data$d==5, digits = 1)),
       "Disease duration" =
         list("min" = ~ min(.data$dis_dur, digits = 1),
              "max" = ~ max(.data$dis_dur, digits = 1),
              "median (IQR)" = ~ qwraps2::median_iqr(.data$dis_dur, digits = 1)) 
    )
whole <- summary_table(df, stats_summary1)
```

The table output does not include the subheadings eg "Disease". It also produces the percentage with a forward slash as eg. 65\%

Answer (score 1):

First, I will create an example dataset to match the provided summary

```r
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(sex     = sample(c("M", "F"), size = 100, replace = TRUE),
                 age_d   = runif(100, 18, 80),
                 d       = sample(1:5, size = 100, replace = TRUE),
                 dis_dur = runif(100, 20, 43),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
str(df)
#> 'data.frame':    100 obs. of  4 variables:
#>  $ sex    : chr  "M" "M" "M" "M" ...
#>  $ age_d  : num  56.8 31.5 31.4 42.1 76.4 ...
#>  $ d      : int  2 1 4 3 5 2 4 2 3 2 ...
#>  $ dis_dur: num  33.3 21.7 23.8 37 30.9 ...
```

load and attach the qwraps2 namespace

```r
library(qwraps2)
```

by default qwraps2 formats output in LaTeX. To have the default switched to
markdown set the following option

```r
options(qwraps2_markup = "markdown")
```

**Update:** as of version 0.5.0 of qwraps2, the use of the `.data` pronoun is
no longer needed or recommended.

```r
stats_summary1 <-
  list("Sex (female)" =
         list("number (%)" = ~ qwraps2::n_perc(sex=="F", digits = 1)),
       "Age" =
         list("min" = ~ min(age_d, digits = 1),
              "max" = ~ max(age_d, digits = 1),
              "median (IQR)" = ~ qwraps2::median_iqr(age_d, digits = 1)),
       "Disease" =
         list("A" = ~ qwraps2::n_perc(d==1, digits = 1),
              "B" = ~ qwraps2::n_perc(d==2, digits = 1),
              "C" = ~ qwraps2::n_perc(d==3, digits = 1),
              "D" = ~ qwraps2::n_perc(d==4, digits = 1),
              "E" = ~ qwraps2::n_perc(d==5, digits = 1)),
       "Disease duration" =
         list("min" = ~ min(dis_dur, digits = 1),
              "max" = ~ max(dis_dur, digits = 1),
              "median (IQR)" = ~ qwraps2::median_iqr(dis_dur, digits = 1)) 
    )
whole <- summary_table(df, stats_summary1)
whole
#> 
#> 
#> |                          |df (N = 100)      |
#> |:-------------------------|:-----------------|
#> |**Sex (female)**          |&nbsp;&nbsp;      |
#> |&nbsp;&nbsp; number (%)   |56 (56.0%)        |
#> |**Age**                   |&nbsp;&nbsp;      |
#> |&nbsp;&nbsp; min          |1                 |
#> |&nbsp;&nbsp; max          |77.6816968536004  |
#> |&nbsp;&nbsp; median (IQR) |52.8 (33.7, 64.8) |
#> |**Disease**               |&nbsp;&nbsp;      |
#> |&nbsp;&nbsp; A            |26 (26.0%)        |
#> |&nbsp;&nbsp; B            |20 (20.0%)        |
#> |&nbsp;&nbsp; C            |15 (15.0%)        |
#> |&nbsp;&nbsp; D            |21 (21.0%)        |
#> |&nbsp;&nbsp; E            |18 (18.0%)        |
#> |**Disease duration**      |&nbsp;&nbsp;      |
#> |&nbsp;&nbsp; min          |1                 |
#> |&nbsp;&nbsp; max          |42.5464100171812  |
#> |&nbsp;&nbsp; median (IQR) |31.0 (25.1, 35.8) |
```

This sould resolve the issue with the forward slash on the percentage sign
(needed escape for LaTeX). Make sure you have the `results = "asis"` chunk
option set so the table will render nicely in your final document.

As for the omitted subheadings, the `qwraps2_summary_table` object is a
character matrix with the class attribute set accordingly and has the
additional attribute `rgroups` which is used by the printing methods to
format the output correctly.

```r
str(whole)
#>  'qwraps2_summary_table' chr [1:12, 1] "56 (56.0%)" "1" "77.6816968536004" ...
#>  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#>   ..$ : chr [1:12] "number (%)" "min" "max" "median (IQR)" ...
#>   ..$ : chr "df (N = 100)"
#>  - attr(*, "rgroups")= Named int [1:4] 1 3 5 3
#>   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "Sex (female)" "Age" "Disease" "Disease duration"
#>  - attr(*, "n")= int 100
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

```r
devtools::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
#>  os       macOS Catalina 10.15.6      
#>  system   x86_64, darwin17.0          
#>  ui       X11                         
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
#>  ctype    en_US.UTF-8                 
#>  tz       America/Denver              
#>  date     2020-09-14                  
#> 
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package     * version date       lib source        
#>  assertthat    0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  backports     1.1.9   2020-08-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  callr         3.4.4   2020-09-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  cli           2.0.2   2020-02-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  crayon        1.3.4   2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  desc          1.2.0   2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  devtools      2.3.1   2020-07-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  digest        0.6.25  2020-02-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  ellipsis      0.3.1   2020-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  evaluate      0.14    2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  fansi         0.4.1   2020-01-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  fs            1.5.0   2020-07-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  glue          1.4.2   2020-08-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  highr         0.8     2019-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  htmltools     0.5.0   2020-06-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  knitr         1.29    2020-06-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  magrittr      1.5     2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  memoise       1.1.0   2017-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  pkgbuild      1.1.0   2020-07-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  pkgload       1.1.0   2020-05-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  prettyunits   1.1.1   2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  processx      3.4.4   2020-09-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  ps            1.3.4   2020-08-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  qwraps2     * 0.5.0   2020-08-31 [1] local         
#>  R6            2.4.1   2019-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  Rcpp          1.0.5   2020-07-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  remotes       2.2.0   2020-07-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  rlang         0.4.7   2020-07-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  rmarkdown     2.3     2020-06-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  rprojroot     1.3-2   2018-01-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  sessioninfo   1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  stringi       1.5.3   2020-09-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  stringr       1.4.0   2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  testthat      2.3.2   2020-03-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  usethis       1.6.1   2020-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  withr         2.2.0   2020-04-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#>  xfun          0.17    2020-09-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.2)
#>  yaml          2.2.1   2020-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.0.0)
#> 
#> [1] /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not really reproducible since you `data` is is not provided.

What worked for me was the following:

- Instead of using the summary statistics arguments from `qwraps2`, I use the ones from the `carpenter` package. This is because in PDF documents rendered through  the `bookdown` package, `qwraps2::mean_sd()` renders the "±" sign as `&plusmn;` in the table. 
  Instead, `carpenter::stat_meanSD()` avoids the "±" sign and uses brackets for the SD instead. You could do another workaround with `paste()` though if you prefer the "±" sign.
- The fact that `qwraps2` is ignoring the top-level headings like `Sex (female)`, `Age` etc. in your example is very annoying. My workaround here is to manually re-introduce these headings through the `kableExtra` package. In you example this would be something like this:

.

```
options(qwraps2_markup = "markdown")

summary_table(df, stats_summary1) %>%
kableExtra::pack_rows("Sex (female)", 1, 1) %>%
kableExtra::pack_rows("Age", 2, 4) %>% 
kableExtra::pack_rows("Disease", 5, 9) %>% 
kableExtra::pack_rows("Disease duration", 10, 12)
```